# How to disable grammar check in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

How do you disable grammar check in Google Chrome? When spell checker is set to "Ask Google for suggestions", Chrome checks for grammar as well as spelling, underlining things it detects as improper in green. Is is easy enough to disable both, but I only want to disable grammar check (Green Underlines), and not spell check, (Red Underlines). How would this be done?